# Drawing in UIView stops working if view width becomes greater than about 16600

Tags: iphone, uiview, drawing

I am using following code to plot graph in a view (in the drawRect method):

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, devicePoint.x, devicePoint.y);

for (index = 1; index < dataCount; index++) {
    devicePoint = [[deviceDataArray objectAtIndex:index] CGPointValue];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, devicePoint.x, devicePoint.y);
}

CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

It works if the `view.bounds.size.width` is less than about 16600.  But above that size the plot stops appearing.

I resize the view depending on the range of the data to be plotted.

Comment: The plot view is a subview and its seems the view stops appears when width becomes greater than 16300 but reappears if size becomes smaller than this threshold.

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad idea to make such huge width for view, you must draw only what user can see in one time (or a little more) and use view of normal (screen) size for this. For controlling where user currently is use UIScrollView.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree view size should not be getting so big.  The view in already in a scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using CAShapeLayers to do the drawing, as they have no actual pixels, just a path that the hardware draws.  Then you could have a UIScrollView which just exposed parts of the CAShapeLayers for drawing, otherwise you are making a huge image with the view as large as you have it currently.

Comment: Thanks. I need to look into that. But I don't understand why it behaves differently on size change.

Comment: Because beyond a certain size it probably refuses to allocate that much memory.  Also, take a look at https://github.com/neror/CA360 for an example of all kinds of uses of CALayer, including CAShapeLayer